# how to use loader in ios 7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode5

Data on my table view controller is very heavy and when I navigate from other table view controller from this then it takes some time as data is fetching from we services. So I think I have to use loader here but I do not know how to use this loader.So can any one help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I think I have to use loader here but I do not know how to use this loader.

What you need is to load your data either on a thread other than the main thread, or asynchronously on the main thread. Start by reading about [how to use NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). There are also many, many blog posts and tutorials written on this topic.